# Lifecycle hooks execute whereas they should not

Tags: angular

In an Angular application, I tried to add

```
window.open("http:www.happyday.com", "_self");
```

inside the constructor of a component class.

I would expect at that point for the new URL to be loaded immediately. Instead, the app executes the code inside the constructor that comes after `window.open()`. Moreover, it executes lifecycle hooks like `ngOnInit`. Of course, it loads the above URL but after executing the whole lifecycle of the component (actually not `ngOnDestroy`). Could someone explain that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Description) about `Window.open()`, the remote URL is loaded asynchronously:

> Note that remote URLs won't load immediately. When window.open()
>   returns, the window always contains about:blank. The actual fetching
>   of the URL is deferred and starts after the current script block
>   finishes executing. The window creation and the loading of the
>   referenced resource are done asynchronously.